# Set toolbarItems property on UINavigationController, or UIViewController displayed in UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to display the same toolbar items in every view of my app. Currently, before I push a view controller I set the toolbarItems property, to the value of the current view controller.

Would I be able to set the toolbarItems property of my navigation controller, and not worry about the toolbarItems property of my individual view controllers?

Comment: I tried setting navigation controller toolbar items `self.navigationController.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:newToolbarItems];`. It doesn't seem to be working, do I have to set it through the current view controllers toolbarItems property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toolbarItems` property of a UINavigationController has no effect on its own toolbar. You should note that it is inherited from UIViewController and only effective if you put that navigation controller inside another navigation controller.

To update the visible toolbar items, you should use `setToolbarItems:animated:` method on the top view controller of the navigation controller.